# Django Migrate Fails due to Type Conflict

Tags: python, django, django-models

Here is my Chapter model code:

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=180)
    is_canon = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    series_id = models.ForeignKey('Series', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

When running `python3 manage.py makemigrations`, I provided a one off value of 'NULL' for the new field `series_id` in order to populate existing rows, when I should have backed out and added `blank=True, null=True` to the definition, as it is now in the code provided above. So, now, I want to run `python3 manage.py migrate`, but of course the migration fails because I've got a bunch of 'NULL' strings in places where django is expecting actual NULL values/integer values.

How to I get rid of those 'NULL' values and reset things so I can migrate?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Delete the migration file or edit it that was created. Then re-do it the proper way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Pythonista comment. You could roll back to the previous migration. Delete the migration file and create it once again. That is the cleanest way in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, Pablo! Yeah... I can't believe I missed that. <_< My bad. Thanks! :D And thanks to you too, Pythonista! :D

Comment: Glad I could help!